# UITableView Data Demand

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hello I am trying to load data on demand.
after data has been loaded the first time, I call the following method.

```
-(void)carregaDados2
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;


    NSURL *url2 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[@"http://localhost:3000/json.aspx?ind=12&tot=12" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

    NSMutableData *data2;
    data2 = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [data2 appendData:response];
    NSMutableData *dt = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [dt appendData:data];
    [dt appendData:data2];
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dt options:nil error:nil];  
    [tableViewjson reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Erro: %@", jsonParsingError);
}
```

However my tableview is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I really do not know what else to do.

Now I changed my code, I can not put my second index the NSMutableArray in my UITableView

```
-(void)carregaDados2
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;


    NSURL *url2 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[@"http://localhost:3000/json.aspx?ind=12&tot=12" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

    NSMutableData *myData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [myData appendData:response];


    NSMutableArray *news2;

    news2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:nil error:&jsonParsingError];
    NSLog(@"LOG: %@", news2);
}
```

Comment: can you post the datasource and delegate methods of your tableView.

Comment: Have you assigned anything to the dataSource property of your table view? Another thing is that sending synchronous requests is not a good idea.

Comment: Have you hooked / setDelegate / print you data etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it you are smashing together two JSON response buffers and trying to parse them as a single JSON message.

```
[dt appendData:data];
[dt appendData:data2];
news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dt options:nil error:nil];
```

This will not work.

For example if `data` is `[{"x"="a","y"="b"}]` and `data2` is `[{"x"="c","y"="d"}]` then `dt` would have the value `[{"x"="a","y"="b"}][{"x"="c","y"="d"}]` which is an invalid JSON message.

I would suggest parsing the JSON messages into NSArrays separately combining the two arrays.

---

Combining two arrays is a basic NSArray/NSMutableArray operation.

```
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *updatedNews = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:nil error:&error];

// If news is of type NSArray…
news = [news arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:updatedNews];

// If news is of type NSMutableArray…
[news addObjectsFromArray:updatedNews];

[tableViewjson reloadData];
```

Comment: I really do not know what else to do.

Now I changed my code, I can not put my second index the NSMutableArray in my UITableView.

Comment: @leedream I updated my answer to demonstrate combining arrays.